# How to play Homeworld: Cataclysm in 1920x1080 32bit?

Tags: technical-issues, homeworld

So I have a modern computer with a fullhd monitor and I want to play Homeworld: Cataclysm in fullscreen, at full resolution and color. But it only lets me select up to 1600x1200 and it looks pretty bad. I tried using the D3D renderer setting the width and height in registry settings manually, but it results in all interface elements misplaced and lines missing to fit the seemingly full picture into a 4:3 square.

How do I get the proper fullhd resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to make the D3D work properly, but OpenGL option worked flawlessly for me. All the UI elements were in proper position.

1. Set the video options to any working OpenGL configuration. It should be 800x600 with 16bit color.
2. Exit the game.
3. Open Registry Editor and find the `Sierra On-Line\Cataclysm` node. On 32bit Windows it should be `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Sierra On-Line\Homeworld`, and on 64bit, it's `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Sierra On-Line\Cataclysm`.
4. Edit the Height, Width and Depth values, but make sure to click the `Decimal` radiobutton so the values are correct (inside parentheses). It should look something like this:

> [image]

Alright, now start the game and have fun with your big monitor!

By the way, the same solution should also work for Homeworld (not Cataclysm).